# Perl: String in Substring or Substring in String

Tags: string, perl, dna-sequence

I'm working with DNA sequences in a file, and this file is formatted something like this, though with more than one sequence:

```
>name of sequence
EXAMPLESEQUENCEATCGATCGATCG
```

I need to be able to tell if a variable (which is also a sequence) matches any of the sequences in the file, and what the name of the sequence it matches, if any, is. Because of the nature of these sequences, my entire variable could be contained in a line of the file, or a line of the variable could be a part of my variable. 
Right now my code looks something like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $filename = "/users/me/file/path/file.txt";
my $exampleentry = "ATCG";
my $returnval = "The sequence does not match any in the file";
open file, "<$filename" or die "Can't find file";
my @Name;
my @Sequence;
my $inx = 0;
while (<file>){
    $Name[$inx] = <file>;
    $Sequence[$inx] = <file>;
    $indx++;
}unless(index($Sequence[$inx], $exampleentry) != -1 || index($exampleentry, $Sequence[$inx]) != -1){
    $returnval = "The sequence matches: ". $Name[$inx];
}
print $returnval;
```

However, even when I purposely set $entry as a match from the file, I still return `The sequence does not match any in the file`. Also, when running the code, I get `Use of uninitialized value in index at thiscode.pl line 14, <file> line 3002.` as well as `Use of uninitialized value within @Name in concatenation (.) or string at thiscode.pl line 15, <file> line 3002.`

How can I perform this search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the purpose of this script is to determine if `$exampleentry` matches any *record* in the file `file.txt`. A *record* describes here a DNA sequence and corresponds to three consecutive lines in the file. The variable `$exampleentry` will match the sequence if it matches the third line of the record. A match means here that either

- `$exampleentry` is a substring of `$line`, or
- `$line` is a substring of `$exampleentry`,

where `$line` referes to the corresponding line in the file.

First, consider the input file `file.txt`:

```
>name of sequence
EXAMPLESEQUENCEATCGATCGATCG
```

in the program you try to read these *two* lines, using *three* calls to [`readline`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html). Accordingly, that last call to readline will return `undef` since there are no more lines to read.

It therefore seems reasonable that the two last lines in `file.txt` are malformed, and the correct format should be:

```
>name of sequence
EXAMPLESEQUENCE
ATCGATCGATCG
```

If I now understand you correctly, I hope this could solve your problem:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "file.txt";
my $exampleentry = "ATCG";
my $returnval = "The sequence does not match any in the file";
open (my $fh, '<', $filename ) or die "Can't find file: $!";
my @name;
my @sequence;
my $inx = 0;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp ($name[$inx] = <$fh>);
    chomp ($sequence[$inx] = <$fh>);
    if (
        index($sequence[$inx], $exampleentry) != -1
        || index($exampleentry, $sequence[$inx]) != -1
    ) {
        $returnval = "The sequence matches: ". $name[$inx];
        last;
    }
}
say $returnval;
```

**Notes:**

- I have changed variable names to follow [snake_case convention](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlstyle.pod). For example the variable `@Name` is better written using all lower case as `@name`.
- I changed the `open()` call to follow the new recommended 3-parameter style, see [Don't Open Files in the old way](http://perlmaven.com/open-files-in-the-old-way) for more information.
- Used feature [say](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) instead of [print](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)
- Added a [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) after each readline to avoid storing newline characters in the arrays.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my poor wording in the question.